# Macport upgrade fails with subversion-perlbindings conflict

Tags: macos, svn, perl, macports

I'm trying to do a `port upgrade outdated`, but it stops on a package conflict that I'm not able to fix.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

```
sudo port upgrade outdated
--->  Computing dependencies for subversion-perlbindings-5.16
Error: Unable to exec port: Can't install subversion-perlbindings-5.16 because 
conflicting ports are installed: subversion-perlbindings-5.12
```

Comment: Do you think my answer below is an acceptable answer to macports?  while brew is an option, there are still people that prefer macports and my answer might be the right answer for them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same problem.  I did:

sudo port deactivate -f subversion-perlbindings-5.12

which allows me to install the new version of the perl bindings.

Comment: I can't confirm that this works with my problem, because I removed macports and installed homebrew. However, if you are saying that you had the same problem, I think your answer should be accepted because it solves the problem. I'll search a little bit more to know if your answer could be accepted.

Comment: another note - right after the deactivate I ran "sudo port install subversion-perlbindings-5.16" and then did a "sudo port update outdated" and everything updated without problem (git, python, php54, mongodb, mysql, curl, etc)  I haven't had any additional problems.

Comment: I'm not sure if they install of the 5_16 version is necessary or it'll happen automatically (I assume the latter) but I'm just including it for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer `brew`: http://brew.sh

There are [tutorials like this](http://bitboxer.de/2010/06/03/moving-from-macports-to-homebrew/) teaching how to port from macports to homebrew.

Comment: I've been told that brew is better than macports in many aspects. If nobody answer the question, suggesting some fix with macports, I think I'll be forced to migrate to brew.

Comment: After one day without other comments, I'll accept your answer, give up macports and install homebrew...

Comment: I had to accept Yehosef's answer, as it was related to macports, although your answer have solved my problem another way.